# Split string by char if followed by any value in list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, split

How do I accomplish to split a string by X, only if X is followed by any of the values in a list?

**Split below by , if next word is in list**

```
first_string = "color=blue,size=xl" # Should be splitted 
second_string = "color=white,pattern=dotted" # Should not be splitted
list = ['size', 'weather', 'mode'];
```

Comment: Welcome back to Stack Overflow. Have you made any attempt to solve the problem yourself first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
first_string = "color=blue,size=xl" # Should be splitted 
second_string = "color=white,pattern=dotted" # Should not be splitted
lst = ['size', 'weather', 'mode']
```

You can check with a for-loop whether you have the value in list. Also make sure you do not use `list` name as a variable name.

```
k=[]
for x in lst:
  if x in first_string:
    k.append(first_string.split(x))
#output
[['color=blue,', '=xl']]
```

This was split since `size` was present in the original list. Similarly, if you would try the same code with the second string it will not split as there are no common values.